# Electron app with Vue issue with icons when build for production

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, icons, electron-builder

I'm creating an app with Electron and Vue 3 using electron-builder and PrimeVue libraries. My app is working fine when running in developement env (npm run electron:serve) but when i build the app for production icons disappear and are replaced by little rectangles.
Launching in debug mode i got this error:

```
Failed to read /primeicons.5f5d08cd.ttf on app protocol [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\_PROJECTS\memories\release\win-unpacked\resources\app\primeicons.5f5d08cd.ttf'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\_PROJECTS\\memories\\release\\win-unpacked\\resources\\app\\primeicons.5f5d08cd.ttf'
}
```

I disabled asar in order to take a look inside vue dist files. Summing up, missing files of icons seems to be under folder "app/fonts" and inside the generated file "app/css/chunk-vendors.0da106f2.css", there are references to these fonts files, for example: "src:url(app:///fonts/primeicons.964f445f.eot)". The problem is that "app://" base path it's wrong, it should be "app://.". Infact, replacing "app://" with "app://." my electron packaged app show correctly all icons. Another manual solution is to copy files inside "app/fonts" folder in "app" folder.

What I'm wondering about is: is there a way to configure Electron, Webpack or something else to write correctly url paths inside that css generated file (app/css/chunk-vendors.0da106f2.css) avoiding to do this manual procedure after build?